# Very difficult to prove a convergent with Weierstrass

Tags: integration, inequality, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

How we can prove that is monotone and bounded:  $I_n=\int _1^n\:e^{-x^3}dx\:$ , Have any ideea how we can solve? and explain all to understand, I am a student...

P.S: for all guys on this site, you do a great job and I respect all because we help each other, and I don't want to see somebody who don't help but makes clever with me... I am at the beginning and don't know...

Comment: Please post the second problem as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the sequence is monotone, consider the difference of two consecutive terms:
$$
I_{n+1} - I_n = \int_1^{n+1} - \int_1^n = \int_n^{n+1} e^{-x^3} dx > 0
$$
which shows that $I_{n+1} > I_n$ for all $n$. We don't need to perform any integration to show this.

To show that the sequence is bounded, we must find a constant such that all $I_n$ are less or equal than this number. To do that, an integration will be necessary, but since we only have to find a (crude) estimate, we are free to change the integrand to make the integral easier, as long as an upper bound results in the end.

Note that $x^3 \ge x$ for $x \ge 1$ and therefore $e^{-x^3} \le e^{-x}$ for $x \ge 1$. Hence for any $n > 1$
$$
\int_1^{n} e^{-x^3}dx \le \int_1^n e^{-x} dx = e^{-1} - e^{-n} < e^{-1} .
$$
So all $I_n$ are bounded from above by the same constant.

Comment: Hi Hans, why you choose in your demonstrate $x^2\:and\:x$ ? why we don't choose something else?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I am about to fix it and add an explanation.

Comment: how you know without solve that $
I_{n+1} - I_n = \int_1^{n+1} - \int_1^n = \int_n^{n+1} e^{-x^3} dx$  ? I calculate and is true, but how did you realize that is equal with $ e^{-x^3}$ without calculate?

Comment: @Lucas - that's a general property of integrals: $\int_a^b f(x) dx  + \int_b^c f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx$. Now rewrite this with $a = 1, b = n, c = n+1$.

Comment: For bounded we can solve with another method?

Comment: Yes, there are many other ways to prove boundedness. Can you think of one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22430/discussion-between-lucas-and-hans-engler).